# CONTEO EN TABLAS RELACIONADAS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas (**Computadoras y Empresas**).

**Computadoras** (la columna empresa hace referencia a la tabla empresas.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Empresas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando MYSQL quiero que al final, me muestre el resultado de cuántas computadoras hay en dichas empresas.

- Empresa A -> 30 Computadoras
- Empresa B -> 23 Computadoras
- Empresa C -> 11 Computadoras

Soy nuevo en MYSQL y de antemano. GRACIAS :)

He estado intentando algo asi:

```
SELECT empresas.name, computers.id
  FROM computers
 INNER JOIN empresas
    ON empresas.id = computers.id;
```

... pero no sé la forma final de contar el resultado con `COUNT`.

Comment: Claro. Lo estaba haciendo algo asi "SELECT
 empresas.name, computers.id
FROM 
 computers
INNER JOIN empresas ON empresas.id = computers.id;" pero no sabia la forma final de contar el resultado con COUNT. Pero gracias por el comentario @sstan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de Eduardo es buena. Lo único es que no aparecerían los empresas sin computadores, si las hay. Para que estas aparezcan en el resultado, hay que usar un `LEFT JOIN`. Y para que el `COUNT` sea correcto, no se puede simplemente contar los registros (`COUNT(*)`), hay que contar los registros que incluya información de computadora (`COUNT(c.id)`):

```
SELECT e.*, COUNT(c.id) AS computer_cnt
  FROM empresas e
  LEFT JOIN computers c
    ON c.empresa = e.id
 GROUP BY e.id
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @sstan. Acabo de verificar el codigo y tienes razon. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la estructura que se plantea se tendría la siguiente consulta:

```sql
SELECT Empresas.id, Empresas.name, COUNT(*) AS "# de Computadoras"
FROM Empresas
INNER JOIN Computadoras ON Computadoras.empresa = Empresas.id
GROUP BY Empresas.id, Empresas.name
```

El resultado de acuerdo a los datos de la gráfica sería el siguiente:

[image: Resultado consulta]

Comment: Gracias por contestar :)